# One JButton can do many action

Tags: java, textbox, jbutton

Why when I press the button it doesn't do anything?. It won't go to the next frame I want on a certain condition I put

```
if(e.getSource()==btn2)
    {
        if (txt5.getText=="20")
        {
           Accept a = new Accept();
           a.setAccept();
           dispose();
        //}
        if (txt5.getText=="5")
        {
           Reject a = new Reject();
           a.setReject();
           dispose();
        }
        if(txt.getText=="10")
        {
           Reserve a = new Reserve();
           a.setReserve();
           dispose();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you put comment `//}` on purpose? If so, the code won't even compile.

Comment: Other than the obvious syntax error (`//}`) there's no way to answer this question currently. How are you setting the text? What's the source of the event? If you put a breakpoint in this method does it get hit?

Comment: paste the whole code with the ActionListener ...

Comment: Even though this doesn't compile, I'm guessing it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java .

Comment: i already remove the // and paste it at actionPerformed but it still wont work

Comment: The code you show does nothing - each 'if' block creates a new object called 'a', then calls a setXxx() method on it, then discards 'a'.

Also, what is txt5 ? Do you mean txt5.getText or txt5.getText() ? And comparing it to a string literal probably does not do what you expect.

Comment: `why when i press the button it doesn't do anything` - add debug code to see if the listener code is being executed. Don't use `==` for String comparisons. Use the `equals(...)` method.